# presentModalViewController just freezes app

Tags: iphone

I currently have a design like follows

View1(mainview) creates a view2, sets a reference back to view1 in view2, presents view2

view2 creates a view3, sets view3 to have the same view1 reference, presents view3

view3 then needs to , depending on user selection, call a function on view1, which currently works perfectly and it should then present view1.

The issue is I need a way of showing view1 when view3 is done, so this reference gets passed along and clearly works because the method called on it executes. The issue I have is when trying to present it the app freezes. I also tried creating a new view1, setting it to the reference and presenting that, this causes a freeze too.

What could be the issue?  I present it like everything else.

Comment: Hard to diagnose without any code. But have you considered just using a UINavigationController?

Comment: Im not sure what code to show. The issue now looks like its the passed around reference to view1, I can call its methods, but I cannot present it. If I create a new view1 and dont set it to the reference and then present it it works, but is obviously a new view, so the old view1 is gone. Im not sure how to solve this. Maybe its because it isnt initialized, if I initialize the view1 first, it works, but also just creates a new view each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling `presentModalViewController` to show the view (as the title suggests) you should call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` for `view3` and `view2` to show `view1` again.

Comment: How would one dismiss 2 views at the same time?

Comment: Did you try dismissing `view2` controller from `view1` controller? obviously, you need to keep a reference to `view2` in `view1` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question, but in the end I passed a pointer along the viewController creation and just used this to dismiss the views. e.g passing in a sender pointer